# Lombok throws error on Eclipse - 4.2

Tags: java, lombok

I am using eclipse 4.2 and Lombok 0.12. Whenever I run any any class with a static main() function, I get the following exception:

Error: Could not find or load main class lombok.core.Main

Comment: Did you add the Lombok Jar as an external library?

Comment: No. We have an internal eclipse plugin tool that resolves dependency chains and adds it to the classpath

Comment: I installed Lobmok by running the jar.

Comment: Did that solve your problem?